# Parsing the command line in jenkins-cli groovy scripts

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-cli

I have written a groovy script to collect some statistics from my Jenkins server, which works ok in the default case. 
However, when I want to pass options to it, I am getting trouble:

(1) The standard groovy CliBuilder exists, but fails to instantiate under jenkins-cli:

```
import jenkins.model.*
import groovy.util.CliBuilder
println("CliBuilder imported; calling constructor...")
def cli = new CliBuilder(usage: 'myscript.groovy [-halr] [name]')
```

results in

```
$ java -jar "jenkins-cli.jar" -s https://myjenkins1/ groovy myscript.groovy
CliBuilder imported; calling constructor...

ERROR: Unexpected exception occurred while performing groovy command.
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/cli/ParseException
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:195)
    at RemoteClass.class$(RemoteClass)
    at RemoteClass.$get$$class$groovy$util$CliBuilder(RemoteClass)
    at RemoteClass.run(RemoteClass:4)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.runScriptOrMainOrTestOrRunnable(GroovyShell.java:266)
....
```

(2) the options starting with a dash are intercepted by jenkins-cli, instead of passing it to the script

```
$ java -jar "jenkins-cli.jar" -s https://myjenkins/ groovy ./myscript.groovy -h
ERROR: "-h" is not a valid option
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar groovy [SCRIPT] [ARGUMENTS ...] [--username VAL] [--password VAL] [--password-file VAL]
Executes the specified Groovy script.
 SCRIPT              : Script to be executed. File, URL or '=' to represent
                       stdin.
 ARGUMENTS           : Command line arguments to pass into script.
 --username VAL      : User name to authenticate yourself to Jenkins
 --password VAL      : Password for authentication. Note that passing a
                       password in arguments is insecure.
 --password-file VAL : File that contains the password
```

Does it mean that the jenkins-cli groovy interface is meant only for simple tasks and should not handle complicated command lines?
Or are these known caveats with known workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

A few issues here:

1. The `jenkins-cli.jar` requires groovy to be piped in via stdin.
2. Command line arguments are read via the `args` array
3. It does appear that args with a `-` are passed to the local `jenkins-cli.jar` and not the groovy script running on the server.

So given the following groovy script saved as `cli.groovy`:

```
println(args)
```

You would run it like this:

```
$ java -jar "jenkins-cli.jar" -s https://myjenkins/ groovy = foo bar baz bat < myscript.groovy
```

Which prints:

```
[foo, bar, baz, bat]
```